# Open xml through excel in python

Tags: python, excel, xml

Can any one help me to open a xml in excel through python.like in c# xlapp.openxml is there any module which do the same stuff

Comment: The xml is not is similar xml format only if it is opened in excel we can do anything in it .i have use etree,win32 but it is of no use

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Google shows me the modules xmltodict, untangle, or xml.etree.ElementTree.